# Tracing requests over their lifetime … through Docker Containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, jaeger, traefik-ingress

Tracing makes finding parts in code, worthwhile a developers time and attention, much easier. For that reason, I attached [*Jaeger*](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) as tracer to a set of microservices inside Docker containers. I use [*Traefik*](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/observability/tracing/jaeger/) as ingress controller/ service-mesh to route and proxy requests.

The problem I am facing is, that something's wrong with the `tracing` config in Traefik. Jaeger can not find the span context to connect the single/ service-dependend spans to a whole trace.

The following line appears in the logs:

```json
{
  "level":"debug",
  "middlewareName":"tracing",
  "middlewareType":"TracingEntryPoint",
  "msg":"Failed to extract the context: opentracing: SpanContext not found in Extract carrier",
  "time":"2021-02-02T23:16:51+01:00"
}
```

What I tried/ searched/ confirmed so far:

- I already checked ports (they are open inside the Docker host network) and everything's reachable. So interconnectivity is not the problem here.
- The forwarding of headers is set via Docker Compose `labels`: `loadbalancer.passhostheader=true`.

---

The following snippets describe the *Docker Compose* setup.

#### Traefik: Ingress Controller

This is a stripped down version of the traefik Container.

```
# Network
ROOT_DOMAIN=example.test
DEFAULT_NETWORK=traefik
```

```yaml
---
version: '3'
services:
    image: "traefik:2.4.2"
    hostname: "controller"
    restart: on-failure
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8082:8082"
      - "8083:8083"
    networks:
      - default
    working_dir: /etc/traefik
    volumes:
      - /private/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ${PWD}/controller/static.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml:ro
      - ${PWD}/controller/dynamic.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic.yml:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - cert-storage:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates:ro
      - ${PWD}/logs/traefik:/var/log/traefik

volumes:
  cert-storage:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ${PWD}/certs/certs

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: ${DEFAULT_NETWORK}
```

Traefik is set up using the *file provider* as base and Docker Compose labels on top of it:

```yaml
# static.yaml (Traefik conf)
debug: true

log:
  level: DEBUG
  filePath: /var/log/traefik/error.log
  format: json

serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
  debug: true

providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    swarmMode: false
    watch: true
    defaultRule: "Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}.example.test`)"
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    network: traefik
  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/dynamic.yml
    watch: true

tracing:
  serviceName: "controller"
  spanNameLimit: 250
  jaeger:
    samplingType: const
    samplingParam: 1.0
    samplingServerURL: http://tracer:5778/sampling
    localAgentHostPort: 127.0.0.1:6831
    gen128Bit: true
    propagation: jaeger
    traceContextHeaderName: "traefik-trace-id"
    collector:
      endpoint: http://tracer:14268/api/traces?format=jaeger.thrift
```

#### Jaeger: Open Tracing/ Open Telemetry

```yaml
---
version: '3'
services:
  tracer:
    image: "jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.21.0"
    hostname: "tracer"
    command:
      - "--log-level=info"
      - "--admin.http.host-port=:14269"
      - "--query.ui-config=/usr/local/share/jaeger/ui/conf.json"
    environment:
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: memory
    restart: on-failure
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    expose:
      - 5775/udp
      - 6831/udp
      - 6832/udp
      - 5778
      - 14250
      - 14268
      - 14269
      - 14271
      - 16686
      - 16687
    volumes:
      - /private/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ${PWD}/tracer/conf:/usr/local/share/jaeger
      - ${PWD}/logs/jaeger:/var/log/@TODO
      - cert-storage:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
    networks:
      - default
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=${DEFAULT_NETWORK}"
      # Admin UI router
      - "traefik.http.routers.tracer-router.rule=Host(`tracer.$ROOT_DOMAIN`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.tracer-router.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.tracer-router.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.tracer-router.tls.options=default"
      - "traefik.http.routers.tracer-router.service=tracer"
      # Service/ Load Balancer
      - "traefik.http.services.tracer.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.tracer.loadbalancer.server.port=16686"
      - "traefik.http.services.tracer.loadbalancer.server.scheme=http"
```

Comment: I don't know the solution, but from that message it looks like Traefik is expecting to participate in an existing trace ID, but is not prepared to start a new Trace. Trying to figure out why that is the case might help you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was with the `traceContextHeaderName`. Sadly I can not tell exactly what the problem was as the `git diff` only shows that nothing changed around traefik and jaeger at the point where I fixed it. I assume config got "stuck" somehow. I tracked down the [related lines in source](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/714a4d4f2d7a963e3e3dee2bf22d51a8f62bde0b/integration/tracing_test.go#L157-L168), but as I am no Go-Dev, I can only guess if there's a bug.

What I did was to switch back to `uber-trace-id`, which magically "fixed" it. After I ran some traces and connected another service (node, npm `jaeger-client` with `process.env.TRACER_STATE_HEADER_NAME` set to an equal value), I switched back to `traefik-trace-id` and things worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is you're experiencing, but here's some things to consider.

According to [this post on the Traefik forums](https://community.traefik.io/t/tracing-with-elastic/5742/4), that message you're seeing is `debug` level because it's not something you should be worried about. It's just logging that no trace context was found, so a new one will be created. That second part is not in the message, but apparently that's what happens.

You should check to see if you're getting data appearing in Jaeger. If you are, that message is probably nothing to worry.

If you are getting data in Jaeger, but it's not connected, that will be because Traefik can only only work with trace context that is already in inbound requests, but it can't add trace context to outbound requests. Within your application, you'll need to implement trace propagation so that your outbound requests include the trace context that was received as part of the incoming request. Without doing that, every request will be sent without trace context and will start a new trace when it is received at the next Traefik ingress point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Graham! You can see my "solution" as separate answer. There wasn't much to fix, aside from switching back to defaults and do some initial runs.